# How to create mouse hover able menu?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, menu

I am new to css and Html.
I would like to create menu like this
https://community.oracle.com/welcome 
How to create it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask You're expected to show what you've tried, and then ask a detailed question if you encounter a specific problem/issue with the code.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sample code for the menu you're looking for.

```js
$('a.hamburger-menu, .dropdown-menu').on('mouseover', function(){
  $(this).parent().addClass('open-dd');
});
$('a.hamburger-menu, .dropdown-menu').on('mouseout', function(){
  $(this).parent().removeClass('open-dd');
});
```

```css
nav{display: block; width: 100%; background: #eee; padding: 20px;
  position: relative}
nav a{color: #555}
.dropdown-menu{width: 200px; background: wheat; position: absolute; display: none}
.dropdown-menu:before{content: ""; display: block;     border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 7px solid wheat;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 8px;}
.dropdown-menu ul{padding: 0; margin: 5px 0 0 0}
.dropdown-menu ul li{display: block}
.dropdown-menu ul li a{color: #333; text-decoration: none; padding: 5px 25px; display: block}
.dropdown-menu ul li a:hover{background: #e6b965}
nav.open-dd .dropdown-menu{display: block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<nav>
  <a href="#" class="hamburger-menu"><i class="fa fa-navicon fa-2x"></i></a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Site map</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```